# Crystal Reports: Showing first row for one field, but sorting on a different field

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, oracle11g, grouping

I have a report that shows three rows per item number with different transaction dates (itemnum, transdate). My issue is either the query or Crystal Reports. I want to sort on another field called UnusedMonths desc, but want to continue showing the most recent row for each ItemNum. I am able to hide the older rows in Section Expert:

```
   Previous ({ItemHistory.ItemNum}) = ({ItemHistory.ItemNum})
```

If I don't group ItemNum first, duplicate ItemNum will appear in the report. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to only select the rows with the latest transdate per itemnum. You can do this by creating a SQL Expression, let's call it `{%MaxDate}`, like:

```
case when "ItemHistory"."ItemNum" is null then null
else (select max(transdate)
      from itemhistory
      where itemnum = "ItemHistory"."ItemNum")
end
```

and then adding the following line to your report's selection formula:

```
{ItemHistory.TransDate} = {%Maxdate}
```

Comment: I do not get a SQL Expression branch in the Field Explorer screen. Is it because I used "Add Command" for my custom union query? There is also mention in the Crystal Reports manual that SQL Expressions will not appear if the query is a Stored Procedure. I don't think my query is one, but I am not sure.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you can't use SQL Expressions if your report uses a SQL Command. You can use similar logic in the command itself, though.

Comment: I do select the most recent transdate by item number within the table, but I was under the impression that using a query like this is problematic when you want to return the entire row and not just the most recent date. Maybe I am confused. I still haven't been able to figure this one out, but I really appreciate your efforts in trying... :)